# How to test a ListActivity by mocking its contentProvider and thus isolate test from database?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, android-testing

I have a ListView activity which loads its data asynchronously from a SQLite database using a ContentProvider.
I want to test this activity but I don't want to use the database. Because I want it to be repeatable.

I'm trying to mock my content provider this way:

```
public class MockRecipeContentProvider extends MockContentProvider{

private List<HashMap<String, String>> results;

@SuppressWarnings("nls")
public MockRecipeContentProvider(){
    super();

    this.results = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    //..populate this.result with som data
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    MatrixCursor mCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {RecipeTable.COLUMN_ID,
                                                          RecipeTable.COLUMN_NAME,
                                                          RecipeTable.COLUMN_INGREDIENTS,
                                                          RecipeTable.COLUMN_DIRECTIONS});

    for(int i =0; i<this.results.size(); i++){
        mCursor.addRow(this.getDataAtPosition(i));
    }
    return mCursor;
}
}
```

And this is my test case:

```
public class MainActivityTest extends  ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity>{

private static final int INITIAL_NUM_ITEMS = 2;
private MainActivity mActivity;

public MainActivityTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);

}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();

    final MockContentResolver mockResolver = new MockContentResolver();
    MockRecipeContentProvider mockContentProvider = new MockRecipeContentProvider();

    mockResolver.addProvider(RecipeContentProvided.AUTHORITY, 
                             mockContentProvider);


    ContextWrapper mActivityContext = new ContextWrapper(
            getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()) {
        @Override
        public ContentResolver getContentResolver() {
            return mockResolver;
        }
    };

    this.setActivityContext(mActivityContext);
    startActivity(new Intent(mActivityContext, MainActivity.class), null, null);

    this.mActivity = getActivity();
}



public void testDisplayCorrectNumOfItems(){
    ListView lv = this.mActivity.getListView();

    assertTrue(lv.getCount()==INITIAL_NUM_ITEMS);
}

}
```

The problem is that the MockRecipeContentProvider.query() is not called, neither the RecipeContentProvider.query(), so the listView is not populate.
What am I doing wrong?

On the other hand, I would like to write an integration test case, extending the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, I would like to test the life cycle etc, but I've read that mocking is not possible if you are extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. So, how can I code a test like this without relaying on the database?

I don't want to use the database because I think that although I will use RenamingDelegatingContext it would cause that the tests wouldn't be repeatable at all, unless that I could drop the test database  and recreate it in the setUp() method. Could this be done?